Django testing: how to keep only one of several test databases?
Seems like this should be simple.  If I have something like this in my Django settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'two': {
        ...
    },
    'three': {
        ...
    },
}

By default, when unit tests run, all three databases are rebuilt, by applying all the migrations.  However, I don't want to rebuild the "expensive" database "three," but using the --keepdb option is obviously not specific enough, as that keeps all the databases.
How do I only keep database "three" when running unit tests?  Thank you in advance.

following is not implemented but you can look into https://github.com/django/django/blob/adae619426b6f50046b3daaa744db52989c9d6db/django/db/backends/base/creation.py#L32 and patch it based on db name

Consider using the SimpleTestCase and specifying the only database you will be using in the database field. If you need more clarification I will write an answer. By default, TestCase, LiveServerTestCase and TransactionTestCase cause the use of all databases.

@Chukwujiobi Canon, thanks, but that doesn't work because all three databases are needed for the unit tests.  I just don't want to always rebuild all three from scratch, hence the desire for a "selective" --keepdb.
